# Spring MVC. Bean null values

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

my controller has an Autowired field "resultados"

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired  
    private CursoDelegate cursoDelegado;

    @Autowired
    private List<Articulo> resultados;

    @RequestMapping(value = "consultarArticulos.html")
    public ModelAndView consultarArticulos() {

        ModelAndView modelAndView= new ModelAndView("consultarArticulos");              
        modelAndView.addObject("resultados", resultados);       
        return modelAndView;        
    }
```

And i define the bean in configuration Class. The method "cursoDelegado.consultarArticulos()" return a collection of three elements but the bean is always empty. There are other class but not needed here

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.myapp")
public class MyConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public List<Articulo> resultados()
    {
        try {
            return cursoDelegado.consultarArticulos();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry, i didnt paste all code but the application run and have all beans declared. The problema is "resultados"

I change the code:

```
@Autowired //MyControllerClass
private @Resource(name="bean1")List<Articulo> resultados;

@Bean(name="bean1")//MyConfigClass
public List<Articulo> resultados()
```

and now its ok. There are any problem with interface list but i dont know the reason. If anyone could explain me the problema :)

Comment: It's possible you're confusing the methods `MyController.consultarArticulos` and `CursoDelegate.consultarArticulos` where the actual problem exists. Post `CursoDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public List<Articulo> resultados(CursoDelegate cursoDelegado)
{
    try {
        List<Articulo> resultados = new ArrayList<Articulo>();
        resultados = cursoDelegado.consultarArticulos();
        return resultados;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*cursoDelegado* is not defined/injected in *MyConfig* so *cursoDelegado.consultarArticulos()* will always throw a NullPointerException. You catch this so it is not visible in your application. The console output (*e.printStackTrace*) should be visible in the server log.

Best to use *cursoDelegado.consultarArticulos()* directly in the controller where *cursoDelegado* is injected.

Comment: i dont copy all code, sorry. The application run but resultados is always null

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.myapp")
public class MyConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean  
    public CursoDelegate cursoDelegado() {
         return new CursoDelegateImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public List<Articulo> resultados()
    {
        try {
            return cursoDelegado().consultarArticulos();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```